# Confusion matrix on regression logistic

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to perform some logistic regression on the dataset provided 
[here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00451/dataR2.csv)) by using the 5-fold-cross-validation.

My goal is to make prediction over the Classification column of the dataset which can take the value 1 (if no cancer) and the value 2 (if cancer).

Here is the full code :

```
     library(ISLR)
     library(boot)
     dataCancer <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00451/dataR2.csv")

     #Randomly shuffle the data
     dataCancer<-dataCancer[sample(nrow(dataCancer)),]
     #Create 5 equally size folds
     folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(dataCancer)),breaks=5,labels=FALSE)
     #Perform 5 fold cross validation
     for(i in 1:5){
           #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
           testIndexes <- which(folds == i)
           testData <- dataCancer[testIndexes, ]
           trainData <- dataCancer[-testIndexes, ]
           #Use the test and train data partitions however you desire...

           classification_model = glm(as.factor(Classification) ~ ., data = trainData,family = binomial)
           summary(classification_model)

           #Use the fitted model to do predictions for the test data
           model_pred_probs = predict(classification_model , testData , type = "response")
           model_predict_classification = rep(0 , length(testData))
           model_predict_classification[model_pred_probs > 0.5] = 1

           #Create the confusion matrix and compute the misclassification rate
           table(model_predict_classification , testData)
           mean(model_predict_classification != testData)
     }
```

I would like to have some help at the end

```
 table(model_predict_classification , testData)
 mean(model_predict_classification != testData)
```

I get the following error :

```
 Error in table(model_predict_classification, testData) : all arguments must have the same length
```

I don't understand very well how to use the confusion matrix.

I want to have 5 misclassification rate. The trainData and testData have been cut into 5 segments. The size should be equal to the model_predict_classification.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `caret` package to perform 5-fold cross validation on the cancer data after splitting it into test and training data sets. Confusion matrices are generated against both the test and training data.

`caret::train()` reports an average accuracy across the 5 hold out folds. The results for each individual fold can be obtained by extracting them from the output model object.

```
library(caret)
data <- read.csv("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00451/dataR2.csv")
# set classification as factor, and recode to 
# 0 = no cancer, 1 = cancer 
data$Classification <- as.factor((data$Classification - 1))
# split data into training and test, based on values of dependent variable 
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$Classification, p = .75,list=FALSE)
training <- data[trainIndex,]
testing <- data[-trainIndex,]
trCntl <- trainControl(method = "CV",number = 5)
glmModel <- train(Classification ~ .,data = training,trControl = trCntl,method="glm",family = "binomial")
# print the model info
summary(glmModel)
glmModel
confusionMatrix(glmModel)
# generate predictions on hold back data
trainPredicted <- predict(glmModel,testing)
# generate confusion matrix for hold back data
confusionMatrix(trainPredicted,reference=testing$Classification)
```

...and the output:

```
> # print the model info
> > summary(glmModel)
> 
> Call: NULL
> 
> Deviance Residuals: 
>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
> -2.1542  -0.8358   0.2605   0.8260   2.1009  
> 
> Coefficients:
>               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   (Intercept) -4.4039248  3.9159157  -1.125   0.2607   Age         -0.0190241  0.0177119  -1.074   0.2828   BMI         -0.1257962  0.0749341  -1.679   0.0932 . Glucose      0.0912229  0.0389587   2.342   0.0192 * Insulin      0.0917095  0.2889870   0.317   0.7510   HOMA        -0.1820392  1.2139114  -0.150   0.8808   Leptin      -0.0207606  0.0195192  -1.064   0.2875   Adiponectin -0.0158448  0.0401506  -0.395   0.6931   Resistin     0.0419178  0.0255536   1.640   0.1009   MCP.1        0.0004672  0.0009093   0.514   0.6074  
> --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> 
> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
> 
>     Null deviance: 119.675  on 86  degrees of freedom Residual deviance:  89.804  on 77  degrees of freedom AIC: 109.8
> 
> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 7
> 
> > glmModel Generalized Linear Model 
> 
> 87 samples  9 predictor  2 classes: '0', '1' 
> 
> No pre-processing Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold)  Summary of
> sample sizes: 70, 69, 70, 69, 70  Resampling results:
> 
>   Accuracy   Kappa    
>   0.7143791  0.4356231
> 
> > confusionMatrix(glmModel) Cross-Validated (5 fold) Confusion Matrix 
> 
> (entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)
>  
>           Reference Prediction    0    1
>          0 33.3 17.2
>          1 11.5 37.9
>                               Accuracy (average) : 0.7126
> 
> > # generate predictions on hold back data
> > trainPredicted <- predict(glmModel,testing)
> > # generate confusion matrix for hold back data
> > confusionMatrix(trainPredicted,reference=testing$Classification) Confusion Matrix and Statistics
> 
>           Reference Prediction  0  1
>          0 11  2
>          1  2 14
>                                           
>                Accuracy : 0.8621          
>                  95% CI : (0.6834, 0.9611)
>     No Information Rate : 0.5517          
>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.0004078       
>                                           
>                   Kappa : 0.7212            Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.0000000       
>                                           
>             Sensitivity : 0.8462          
>             Specificity : 0.8750          
>          Pos Pred Value : 0.8462          
>          Neg Pred Value : 0.8750          
>              Prevalence : 0.4483          
>          Detection Rate : 0.3793              Detection Prevalence : 0.4483          
>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.8606          
>                                           
>        'Positive' Class : 0               
>                                           
> >
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious help. If I understand well confusionMatrix(glmModel) give the current accuracy on the dataset and confusionMatrix(trainPredicted,reference=testing$Classification) give the accuracy on the training data. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Ilan - the first confusion matrix uses the training data, the second uses the test data, which was not used to create the model. Validating the model against data that wasn’t used to build the model helps us see whether the model overfit the training data.

Comment: In case I want to reuse the code for a regression tree classification. I just have to replace glmModel by treeModel <- train(Classification ~., data = training, method = "rpart", parms = list(split = "information"),trControl=trCntl,tuneLength = 10) 
and Add plot(treeModel$finalModel) and text(treeModel$finalModel).
Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes, but the tree plot will be easier to read if you use plot(treeModel$finalModel,uniform=TRUE, margin=.3)
text(treeModel$finalModel,use.n=TRUE,all=TRUE, cex=.9)

Comment: Thanks. If I use the caret library can I use model selection to select a pertinent subset of features and draw the Error-rate versus flexibility curve (to choose the best level of flexibility)?